# How to load the data to tableview from database using javafx

Tags: java, javafx

i am beginner of javafx. i just use way java jtable like load the data but i couldn't load the data to tableview what i tried so far i attached below.how to load the data to tableview

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> table1;

public void table_load()
{
    int c;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/addressbook", "root","");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from records");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rd = rs.getMetaData();
        c = rd.getColumnCount();
        df = (DefaultTableModel)table1.getCellData(0);
        df.setRowCount(0);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Vector v = new Vector();
            for (int i=1; i<=c; i++)
            {
                v.add(rs.getString("id"));
                v.add(rs.getString("name"));
                v.add(rs.getString("address"));
                v.add(rs.getString("phone"));
            }
            df.addRow(v);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a Swing model with JavaFX.  You must create a data class, and pass an ObservableList of objects of that class to the TableView’s `setItems` method.  (I personally would name that data class `Record`.)

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: _i am beginner of javafx_ which means that your first steps would be reading and (trying to, at least) understanding a basic tutorial on how to use TableViews :) The javafx tag wiki has references to some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't add the data to a TableColumn directly. The usual way would be to have objects of a type you can add. Let's assume your result set would contain objects of type `Customer` and you could extract one or many customer objects from your result set. Then you would rather work with the following (need to be defined in the `fxml` file:

- A superordinate table like `TableView <Customer> customerView`
- a number of table columns like:

  - `TableColumn<Customer, String> idColumn`
  - `TableColumn<Customer, String> nameColumn`
  - `TableColumn<Customer, String> addressColumn`
  - `TableColumn<Customer, String> phoneColumn`

You need to set the value factory for the columns to make clear which attribute is to be displayed.

- `idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("[ATTRIBUTE NAME IN CUSTOMER CLASS]"));`

like

- `idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));`

The last step should be to fill the table view with data:

`customerView.setItems(observableCustomers);`

where `observableCustomers` is a list of type `ObservableList<Customer>`.   `javafx.collections.FXCollections` will help you here to create a corresponding object.

It should be similar to this:

```
@FXML
TableView <Customer> customerView;

@FXML
TableColumn<Customer, String> idColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn<Customer, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn<Customer, String> addressColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn<Customer, String> phoneColumn;

ObservableList<Customer> observableCustomers;

// init method or constructor, whatever suits your needs
private void initTable() {

    observableCustomers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("address"));
    phoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phone"));
}

public void table_load()
{

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/addressbook", "root","");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from records");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rd = rs.getMetaData();

        // CAST/TRANSFORMATION TO BE DONE BY YOU
        List<Customer> customerList = ((List<Customer>) rs.toList());

        // only if necessary
        observableCustomers.clear();
        // add customers
        observableCustomers.addAll(customerList);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use PropertyValueFactory.  It is based on reflection, which means it is error prone and the errors cannot be caught by the compiler.  And the errors don’t even appear at runtime;  PropertyValueFactory apparently swallows them.  `nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().nameProperty())` is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Swing, a JavaFX TableView does not use a separate model.  Instead, the data *is* the model.  You pass this data to the TableView using the TableView’s setItems method.

This means you need to create a class to hold your data.  Since your table is called `records`, I would name the data class `Record`.

If you look at the documentation of JavaFX classes, you should notice a pattern.  *Bean properties* are encapsulated attributes, which consist of three methods:

- A read method, which always starts with `get` followed by a capital letter.¹
- A write method, which always starts with `set` followed by a capital letter.²
- A property method, whose name always ends with `Property`.

For instance, consider the [javafx.stage.Window](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html) class.  It has an “opacity” property, which is represented by these methods:

- [double getOpacity()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#getOpacity%28%29)
- [void setOpacity(double)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOpacity%28double%29)
- [DoubleProperty opacityProperty()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#opacityProperty%28%29)

Your data class needs to follow the same pattern:

```
public class Record {
    private final StringProperty id;
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final StringProperty address;
    private final StringProperty phone;

    public Record() {
        id = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "id");
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        address = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "address");
        phone = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "phone");
    }

    public StringProperty idProperty() { return id; }
    public String getId() { return id.get(); }
    public void setId(String newId) { id.set(newId); }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public void setName(String newName) { name.set(newName); }

    public StringProperty addressProperty() { return address; }
    public String getAddress() { return address.get(); }
    public void setAddress(String newAddress) { address.set(newAddress); }

    public StringProperty phoneProperty() { return phone; }
    public String getPhone() { return phone.get(); }
    public void setPhone(String newPhone) { phone.set(newPhone); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[id=%s, name=%s]",
            getClass().getName(), getId(), getName());
    }
}
```

Creating these objects is straightforward:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Record> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> idColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> nameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> addressColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> phoneColumn;

// ... 

    ObservableList<Record> records = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            record.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            record.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            record.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));

            records.add(record);
        }
    }

    table.setItems(records);
```

Instead of a table model, you must instead tell each table column which data it should display:

```
idColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().idProperty());
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().nameProperty());
addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().addressProperty());
phoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().phoneProperty());
```

---

¹ Read methods whose return type is primitive boolean may use `is` instead of `get`.
² Write methods are not needed for read-only properties.